# Another form of Second Order ODE solution with two distinct real roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose i have ODE:

$y''-4y=0$

We know that the solution is

$y=c_1 e^{2x} + c_2 e^{-2x}$

And I realize that this also has the following solution

$y=c_1 \cosh(2x) + c_2 \sinh(2x)$

are the two solutions equivalent?

So, if i have this ODE

$ay''-by=0\qquad a>0, b>0$

May I write the general equation as follows?

$y=c_1 \cosh(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x) + c_2 \sinh(\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}x)$

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the two solutions are equivalent (with *different* values of $c_1$ and $c_2$). If you have the first solution, you can always re-write it in the form of the second solution, and vice versa. Yes, your last expression is the general solution.

Comment: It's simply a changing of the basis. Instead of $(e^{2x},e^{-2x})$ you take $(\cosh(2x),\sinh(2x))$. Of course coordinates, $c_1,c_2$, will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the two forms of solutions are equivalent.

Any linear combination of $e^{\lambda_1x}$ and $e^{\lambda _2x}$ is a solution

Hyperbolic functions are linear combinations of exponentials.